# Can't send science back to Kerbin

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've landed a mobile processing lab on Mün, have a scientist, an engineer and a pilot, and I was thinking about an exploration mission.

But it seems I can't send science back to Kerbin.

When I tell the mobile processing lab to "Transmit Science" I get the message:

> cannot transmit data: no available in-range antenna on this vessel

But I have 3 HG-5 HG antennas.

Now I made some mistake so the antenna are pointing to the ground, but I've tried having the ship fall, and still it doesn't work.

Any idea space citizens?

[image: Screenshot from the game]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the top-left of your picture near "MET", there is a set of icons, **they display the comm status of your ship**. These are important when you want to transmit science or control automated probes. You can hover on them with the mouse to have more information, here :

- ship is "kerbal capable", anyone can put a manoever node (a pilot is on board or you are playing science or sandbox mode)
- 0% signal strength
- no science data can be transmitted
- no connection to Kerbin

**You must be on the hidden side of Mun, therefore you cannot transmit science since you don't have a line of sight with Kerbin.**

Antennae orientation is not important for transmission or control, they just need to be deployed.

Near Mun and Minmus, any antenna (except for those embedded in command pods and probes) is sufficient. For example the [Communitron 16](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Communotron_16) (radial, to avoid forgetting to deploy it) and the [HG-5](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/HG-5_High_Gain_Antenna) are OK and cheap. You can see the range of the other antennae [here](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/CommNet).

As you did in your answer, either put a ship nearby with a **relay** antenna or land on the other side. You can also bring back the science to Kerbin to have additional points!

Here are other examples of display:

[image: full connection]

- probe capable ship (manoever nodes, precise throttle,...)
- very high signal
- transmissible science (data goes out of ship)
- direct connection to Kerbin

[image]

- probe capable ship
- very low signal
- **relayed signal (via xenosatjool)**
- transmissible science
- direct connection to Kerbin
- (map view only) signal jump filter to show how is transmitted the signal

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution, these antennaes seem to be quite weak, using another spaceship as relay between the Mün and Kerbin I could transmit science back home.

Comment: Those antennas should be able to reach back to Kerbin.  Did you have line of sight before adding a relay?

Comment: I think I landed on the hidden side of Mün as @Goufalite said, hence the transmission issues. I didn't know the moon was not rotating on itself :'D

Comment: @Loïc Mun is rotating, about once every 6 days, that's why your ship will experience both day and night. It is however, like our own moon, rotating at speed that keeps the same side of Mun facing Kerbin at all times. Or more to the point, the side you landed on will always be facing away from Kerbin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking